# Travis-CI: Class not found even when using autoloader

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci, autoloader

Im kind of new with Travis, and I am expreimenting with it right now. I uploaded have my PHP Project on [Github](https://github.com/ezylot/PHPSkeleton) and when I let it test via [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/ezylot/PHPSkeleton) it fails and gives me this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'controllers\Welcome' not found in /home/travis/build/ezylot/PHPSkeleton/tests/controllers/welcomeTest.php on line 4
```

I use a autoloader to load the classes, and it is no problem on my local machine. I include the autoloader in bootsrap.php with the bootstrap in the PHPUnit Konfiguration-XML File.

```
<?php
if (!@include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php') {
    die('You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands:
        wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
        php composer.phar install');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely developing on OSX which has case insensitive filesystem and tests pass. Travis uses case sensitive file system. Try renaming `app/controllers/welcome.php` to `app/controllers/Welcome.php`.

In general it is good idea to follow [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) standard to avoid autoloading issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had a short php open tag at the top of the class file.

```
<?
```

as opposed to

```
<?php
```

This broke it on the remote, but not on my local. Which is weird, because I would've expected it to break locally too.

Putting this out there in case someone else is in the same odd situation.

Comment: Definitely a valid point to look out for, but my problem was the different case-sensitivity handling in Windows and Linux.